# How do I fix this error about a missing class?

Tags: commerce

I'm using the [Commerce Canada Post](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_canadapost) module.

The code in the [src/Plugin/Commerce/ShippingMethod/CanadaPost.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce_canadapost/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Plugin/Commerce/ShippingMethod/CanadaPost.php) file uses a `CanadaPost\Rating` class which isn't defined that namespace and it causes an error.

The [src/Api/RatingService.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce_canadapost/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Api/RatingService.php) file contains the following code.

```php
/**
 * Returns an initialized Canada Post Rating service.
 *
 * @param array $api_settings
 *   The Canada Post API settings.
 *
 * @return \CanadaPost\Rating
 *   The rating service class.
 */
protected function getRequest(array $api_settings) {
  $config = $this->getRequestConfig($api_settings);

  return new Rating($config);
}
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CanadaPost\Rating class is not part of the *Commerce Canada Post* module, rather it's part of a dependency, the [PHP Canada Post API](https://github.com/thejacer87/php-canadapost-api), that should be installed into your vendor directory by composer in the thejacer87/php-canadapost-api subdirectory.

If it's not there, then my best guess is that you tried to install Commerce Canada Post without using composer. Install it, the Commerce Canada Post module, with composer and the dependency will be installed and it'll resolve your error.

See [Download contributed modules, themes and their dependencies using Composer](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#managing-contributed) on drupal.org for how to install a module with composer.

```
composer require drupal/commerce_canadapost
```

Comment: Thanks @sonfd for clear explanation
after install thejacer87/php-canadapost-api through composer now its working.
you save my day.